# Scroll to top animate not scrolling down after

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrolltop

I've got a scroll to top button on my web page that has an animate function to scroll smoothly to the top when pressed. That feature works 100% but after it scrolled to the top it doesn't allow me to normally scroll down again. It's like the function keeps running.

Here is my code:

```
    $(window).scroll(function(){
            var scroll = $('#scroll');
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
                  scroll.fadeIn('slow');
            }
            else  {
                scroll.fadeOut('slow');
            }

            $('#scroll-image').on('click', function(){
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 1}, 800);
            return false;
            });
        });
```

Any suggestions? And thanks in advance!

Edit: Here is my HMLT

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="google-site-verification" content="D5eWVqc8lqeGSw4BjMank9FS8Dy4lusI7dxEm9qHtzI" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <a id="toggle" class="toggleClassOff">≡</a>
            <nav id="navbar" class="navbarClassOff">
                <ul id="navbarUl">
                    <li><a href="index.html">About Me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="skills.html">Skills</a></li>
                    <li><a href="qualifications.html">Qualifications</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div id="scroll">
            <a href="#" id="scroll-image"><img src="images/top-button.png"></a> 
        </div>
        <div id="about-page-container">
            <img id="about-page-image" src="images/question.png">
            <div id="about-page" class="about-page-class-off">
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="contentClassOff">
            <h1></h1>
            <img src="images/2009-English-Certificate.jpg" alt="Can't find image">
            <img src="images/2010-English-Certificate.jpg" alt="Can't find image">
            <img src="images/Senior-Certificate.jpg" alt="Can't find image">
            <h1></h1>
            <img src="images/comptiaA.jpg" alt="Can't find image">
            <img src="images/comptiaN.jpg" alt="Can't find image">
            <img src="images/first-aid.jpg" alt="Can't find image">
            <img src="images/rope-access.jpg" alt="Can't find image">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,400italic|Oswald);

* {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    margin: 0;
}

body{
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('images/wallpaper1.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

/*
//////////////////////////
/ToggleToggleToggleToggle
//////////////////////////
*/
.toggleClassOff{
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 3.0em;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0.2em;
    left: 1em;
    left: 0.6em;
    z-index: 1;
    color: #fff;
}
.toggleClassOn{
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 3.0em;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0.2em;
    left: 1em;
    left: 4.4em;
    z-index: 1;
    color: #fff;
}

/*
/////////////////////////
/NavbarNavbarNavbarNavbar
/////////////////////////
*/
.navbarClassOff {
    position: fixed;
    width: 12em;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100vh;
    left: -12em;
    background-color: #666;
}
.navbarClassOn {
    position: fixed;
    width: 12em;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100vh;
    left: 0em;
    background-color: #666;
}

#navbarUl {
    margin-top: 2em;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#navbarUl > li {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: -2.5em;
    width: 10.4em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 3em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
#navbarUl >li:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
}
#navbarUl > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ff6600;
    display: block;
    font-weight: 300;
}
/*
/////////////////////////////
/ContentContentContentContent
/////////////////////////////
*/
#content{
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.contentClassOff{
    position: relative;
    width: 70vw;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0em;
    top: 3em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.9;
    padding: 1em;
}
.contentClassOn{
    position: relative;
    width: 70vw;
    margin: auto;
    left: 5em;
    top: 3em;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.9;
    padding: 1em;
}
#content > p {
    width: 100%;
}

#content h1 {
    position: relative;
    border-top: 1px solid #666;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
}
#id-photos-container{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
.id-photos{
    float: left;
    height: 280px;
    width: 280px;
}
.id-photos:first-child {
    margin-left: 60px;
}

/*
p > iframe {
    width: 100%;
}
*/
/*
/////////////////////////////////////////
/TransitionTransitionTransitionTransition
/////////////////////////////////////////
*/
.toggleClassOff, .navbarClassOff, .contentClassOff {
    transition: left 0.4s ease-in;
}

/*
/////////////////////////////////////////
/About-Page Section
/////////////////////////////////////////
*/
#about-page-container > img {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 3%;
    top: 6%;
    z-index: 10;
    animation-name: img-size;
    animation-iteration-count: 3;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}
@keyframes img-size {
    0% {height: 80px; width: 80px}
    50% {height: 120px; width: 120px;}
    100% {height: 80px; width: 80px;}
}

.about-page-class-off {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 300px;
    height: 220px;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: #666;
    border-radius: 10px;
    top: 100px;
    right: 100px;
    padding: 18px;
}
.about-page-class-on {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 300px;
    height: 220px;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #666;
    border-radius: 10px;
    top: 100px;
    right: 100px;
    padding: 18px;
}
.about-page-class-off {
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
}

#about-page > p {
    color: #ff6600; 
   /* color: #fff; */
   /* color: #ad33ff; */
    font-size: 1.4em;
}

/*
/////////////////////////////////////////
/Scroll to top Scroll to top Scroll to top
/////////////////////////////////////////
*/

#scroll {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10%;
    right: 3%;
    z-index: 20;
    display: none;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

:focus {outline:none;}
```

Comment: Can I look into your html code?

Comment: Sure! Which part do you want to see? Only the button div or the whole document?

Comment: You can share whole documnent

Comment: Edited my original question to include it!

Comment: your css is  missing. plz share it as well.

Comment: Shared it after the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put logic to handle click event inside scroll event handler. 
What your code does is,

1. User scroll through the page
2. For each scroll, a click event will be registered.
3. For ex, when user scroll to bottom of page, scroll event will be emitted 100s of times. So click event will be registered hundreds of times.
4. Now whenever you click scroll to top button, all those registered click event will be fired.
5. Now when you scroll more before all already registered events completed, more click events will be registered and thats what causing you the problem.

---

**Solution**

JsBin - http://jsbin.com/zaxakuniju/1/edit?html,js,output
(Click Last image to scroll to top)

```
$(function () {
    $('#scroll-image').on('click', function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 1}, 800);
        return false;
    });

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var scroll = $('#scroll');
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
            scroll.fadeIn('slow');
        } else {
            scroll.fadeOut('slow');
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I understand now where i went wrong. It's working now :)

Comment: You are welcome! Always make sure to register event handlers inside $(function () {})(https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Answer (score 1):

try moving the click event outside of scroll:

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
            var scroll = $('#scroll');
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
                  scroll.fadeIn('slow');
            }
            else  {
                scroll.fadeOut('slow');
            }

        });

            $('#scroll-image').on('click', function(){
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 1}, 800);
            return false;
            });
```

jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/zmp1ghat/